# How to divide table to get result below?

Tags: sql, group-by, partitioning

I have table 1 with

```
 msisdn_b  msisdn_a  event 
 1111      222      0 
 1111      333      0 
 1111      777      1 
 2222      567      0 
 2222      571      1 
 2222      572      1
```

And I want to have a result like table 2, where I divide the sum of occurrences by number of occurrences for each msisdn_b.

```
msisdn_b  event_rate  
1111      0,333333333 
2222      0,666666667
```

Do I use partition by clause ? or group by will be enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select msisdn_b, avg(event * 1.0)
from t
group by msisdn_b;
```

The `* 1.0` is simply because some database calculate integer averages -- so the result is an integer rather than a number with decimals.  Your database might not behave that way.